# datetime (day out of range) Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a problem with my script.

```
end = date(2012, 6, 20)
start = date(2012, 5, 01)
delta = end - start
delta = delta.days
print 'The number of days taken into account for training periods testing:', delta

all_training_periods=[pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2012, 5, 01+k),end=dt.datetime(2012, 6,20),freq='10T') for k in range(0,delta)]
```

The problem is that I have an error message telling me:

```
  File "<ipython-input-192-57c97670a7f1>", line 1, in <module>
    all_training_periods=[pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2012, 5, 01+k),end=dt.datetime(2012, 6,20),freq='10T') for k in range(0,delta)]

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

The thing here is that I want different training period from the 1st of May to the 20th of June, from the 2nd of May to the 20th of June, ..., from the 19th of June to the 20th of June.

Comment: what happens when k is, say, 32? you think may the 33rd is going to parse?

Comment: please `pep8` your code, and besides, what's `01+k`, by octal notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
end = date(2012, 6, 20)
start = date(2012, 5, 01)
delta = end - start
```

Where `delta.days` evaluates 50. Then in your line:

```
dt.datetime(2012, 5, 01+k)
```

will end up with something like:

```
dt.datetime(2012, 5, 01+49)
```

Then `datetime` will throw exception since May do not have 49 days. No month have more than 31 days.

Try this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
dt.datetime(2012, 5, 01) + timedelta(days=k)
```

This will make the correct calculation.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to increment dates like this:

```
datetime.date(2012, 5, 1) + datetime.timedelta(k, 0)
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. What is `x`? What does the 2nd function call do?

Comment: Nah, don't want to elaborate. Thanks for noticing, indeed `s/x/k/`, applied. `k` is OP's variable.

Comment: Thanks guys!You are funny anyway but it works... thanks for the help